# How to get all tenants in stancl/tenancy package?

Tags: collections, laravel-8, multi-tenant

I am using  [stancl/tenancy](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/) im project, but I can not find a method in documentation which could iterate over all tenants and switch to current tenant in iteration. Is there something like that? For example [Laravel/Multitenanc](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v3/advanced-usage/looping-over-a-collection-of-tenants)y package has Tenant::all()->eachCurrent() method which do exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the `run()` [method](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/tenants).  For example to dump all users for all tenants:

```
Tenant::all()->each( function($tenant) {

    $tenant->run(function () {
        // This will be run in the tenant context
        dump(User::all());
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch between tenants you can use this:

```
tenancy()->initialize($tenantid);
```

Than check if the current tenant by:

```
$currentTenant = tenant('id');
```